# app.autodiscover_tasks() TypeError: autodiscover_tasks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'packages'

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to use celery in my django app. But, I was getting an error, so I copied the code from the book I was following(Django 3 by example). Now, when I run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command, I get this error:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks() TypeError: autodiscover_tasks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'packages'
```

Here is my `celery.py`, where the error is:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myshop.settings')

app = Celery('myshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Here is my complete error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\myshop\myshop\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\online-shop\myshop\myshop\celery.py", line 10, in <module>
    app.autodiscover_tasks()
TypeError: autodiscover_tasks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'packages'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the version of celery?

Comment: I have just installed it now, so its the latest one.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the latest one. Please add the ***complete error traceback***

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I suspect you are not on the latest version. Check the version by ***`celery --version`*** command. If you get  *5.X* you are good

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out. But, after I upgraded to celery==5.0.2, I got this warning:

Comment: ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

django-celery 3.3.1 requires celery<4.0,>=3.1.15, but you'll have celery 5.0.2 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Celery version 3.x
app.autodiscover_tasks() only works on version 4.x

Try to use:

```
from django.apps import apps
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

Comment: I did that. But, now I am getting another error that says :    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.task'. How do i resolve this?